# Read separate web.config file outside the application folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, config

I need to read `web.config` file, outside the application's folder (located in any other directory). 
I tried this code:

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\Idrees\Downloads\New folder\Web.config";
Configuration c1 = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(filePath);
var value1 = c1.AppSettings.Settings["Key1"].Value;
```

But it is giving me the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Because here, `c1.AppSettings` is an object, but `c1.AppSettings.Settings` contains not items (hence `0` Count). It is not really loading the `AppSettings` keys. When trying to read any `Key` from `Settings` collection, it gives this error.

Is there any way how to load `AppSettings` keys from a `web.config` file outside the application folder.

If I put same file within application folder, then it reads the keys successfully.

This is my sample config file's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--             
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit 
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433    
  -->
<configuration>        
  <connectionStrings>        
    <!--here goes my connection strings-->
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Key1" value="Value1" />
    <add key="Key2" value="Value2" />
    <add key="Key3" value="Value3" />
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

I have a web application already running on my server. And I need to develop a small utility which has to do some job in database, and I don't want to write db credentials or connection string(and some other additional app-settings) in each application, I want it to read same thing from web.config.

Comment: Use XDocument Class instead ?

Comment: Thanks @DevC. Is there any reason we can't read using ConfigurationManager class?

Comment: You need that web.config just to load app settings? If that's the case why don't you use a json file and parse it?

Comment: I have a web application already running on my server. Now I need to develope a small utility which has to do some job in database, and I don't want to write db credentials or connection string(and some other additional app-settings) in each application, I want it to read same thing from web.config.

Comment: @M_Idrees I think your last comment could be added to your question because it give us your intent of what you really want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can using `ConfigurationManager` to read arbitrary configuration files by opening a *mapped* exe configuration as follows:

```
var filePath = @"C:\Users\Idrees\Downloads\New folder\Web.config";
var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = filePath };
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var value = configuration.AppSettings.Settings["Key1"].Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand from your comment you want some kind of shared configuration accross multiple app on the same computer. You may consider using external file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup> 
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

  <connectionStrings configSource="config\connString01.config"/>

  <appSettings file="config\config01.config">
    <add key="Var3" value="Var3 value from main config file"/>
  </appSettings>
```

in above .config example connectionStrings is sourced from an other file. Below an example what can be such an external config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SQLConnectionString01" connectionString="Data Source=sourcename01;Initial Catalog=cat01;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=true;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing another option.

Answer (score 1):

Read documentation: [ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static Configuration OpenExeConfiguration(
    string exePath
)
```

> This is EXE path

Comment: I think, If this is the file-path/file-name problem, then it should not even able to read from file. it should give error on the first line of loading.

Comment: @M_Idrees you don't need to guess, you have documentation

Comment: So it means there is no way to read web.config file from Console Application using ConfigurationManager class? Or it may have provided some other alternative in ConfigurationManager class, but I may be using the wrong function?