# Blazer Server App - Add web.config settings

Tags: web-config, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app that is running under IIS.  I see that it generates a web.config file upon publish with some settings in it.

I need to add some more settings to the web.config as they are used by another component (asp.net 4 app).  Does anyone know which file I need to create/modify in order to be able to add these values.

At this stage I do not need to use transforms on the web.config, but it would be nice to know this as well.

Comment: You can use the ConfigurationManager to read arbitrary configuration files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49378344/read-separate-web-config-file-outside-the-application-folder (see first answer)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. However, I need to add new settings to it during development and the file appears to be auto generated.  Just wondering which file I need to update (say an app.settings or something) so that it picks up the additional settings.

Comment: Production web.config on server is often (always) different from the dev version. So it is usual not to redeploy this file and to maintain these 2 versions manually.

Answer (score 3):

What I found is that the web.config works as per Asp.Net Core documentation.  In brief for a Blazor server app hosted under IIS (this is my understanding)

- If there is no web.config existing in the root of the project directory, one is created during the build and copied to the bin directory. It will contain default information.
- If a web.config exists in the root of the project directory, it is copied to the bin folder unmodified (note: it requires some default settings inside).
- If transforms exist, they will be applied.

I didn't realise that the web.config is created if it did not exist hence my original question.

Also, I have not been able to get transforms to work yet.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you publish the project the web.config in the root gets ignored and uses the auto-generated one.

Adding this to my blazor project file solved it and can see the web.config getting published to Azure now:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PublishIISAssets>true</PublishIISAssets>
```