# Hosting Blazor WASM on Azure webp images not loading

Tags: azure, blazor-webassembly, webp

I have a blazor web assembly project. In images folder I have a mixture of jpg and webp images. When I publish the client to Azure all of the jpg images work fine and all of the webp images do not. Looking at the browser's inspector I see along with the image name

```
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404(not found)
```

I have my images in razor with their source paths like this

```
<img src="/images/Audiolithe.webp" />
<img src="/images/about.jpg" />
```

The issue is there for both Google and Firefox so I don't believe it is browser specific and from my understanding all modern browsers support webp images.

I had read somewhere that the issue may be the leading backslash in front of 'images' but removing that made no difference on the published website.

**Update**
I added the web.config file

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I copied the autogenerated one and added

```
 <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
```

so it now looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I published my site to Azure and it still did not fix the issue. After that I did a search in the folder of my project and any web.config files that popped up did have the webp mimemapping.

I did some searching and tried what Rob C suggested in [Blazer Server App - Add web.config settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68124616/blazer-server-app-add-web-config-settings)

and it works! Thank you Harshitha for getting me pointed in the right direction.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rPo3.png

Comment: Does the images folder exists in the `wwwroot` folder of the deployed app?

Comment: Iam able to load `webp` extension image [1](https://i.imgur.com/P4Ybtr2.png) and [2](https://i.imgur.com/WJVBNY2.png) by adding configuration in `web.config` file.Will post an answer in detail.

Comment: Adding `<mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />` in `web.config` file will allow you to load `.webp` images.

Comment: Have you tried by adding it in the  default `web.config` in wwwroot folder ?

Comment: First check the same in the default web.config file to make sure mimetype is working.Later you can add your own web.config file.

Comment: Glad it worked out.

Comment: I moved the web.config to my wwwroot folder and when I published it I got 'The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.' I am going to move it back to the root and implement Rob C's answer as well since that works.

Comment: The web.config has to be in the root folder of the deployed app.If you add it in the local wwwroot folder, then it gets published to site/wwwroot/wwwroot,results in the error (as you have seen ).

Answer (score 0):

I have added images folder in `wwwroot` directory of the Blazor WASM application.

[image]

- Add tried to display the images in `Index.razor`.
- Initially even I got the same error.

> ```cs
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> ```

- We need to explicitly add the configuration in `web.config` file to allow the `.webp` extension images.
- When we deploy the Web App to Azure App service `web.config` file will be generated with some default settings in the root directory of the application.

[image]

- I have added the below mimemap setting in`web.config` file.

```cs
<mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
```

***Output:***
[image]

[image]

***NOTE:***

Whenever you re-publish the webapp, the settings in the `web.config` file which you have done in portal will be lost.

If you don't want this type of behavior, add a web.config in the local webapp and publish with the specified changes.