# Azure Error The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable when opening a pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have an asp.net website in Azure. In that website there is directory of pdf's.  When I try and open one it comes up with the error "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."  The pdf does exist.

The url it is trying to open is

"https://....azurewebsites.net/PdfForms/1111-1858jj-84090-8392-c4365d03b5c1/Section_4364.pdf"

My code creates a hyperlink for each of the pdfs and is the following -

```
if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        HyperLink hyperLink = new HyperLink();
        hyperLink.NavigateUrl = "../PdfForms/" + dr[0].ToString() + "/" + Utility.CleanUrl(dr[1].ToString()) + ".pdf";
        hyperLink.Text = dr[1].ToString() + " - uploaded on " + dr[2].ToString();
        hyperLink.Target = "_blank";

        Literal li = new Literal();
        li.Text = "<br><br>";

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(hyperLink);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(li);
    }

}
else
{ 

    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = "There are no forms for you to download";

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to see the pdf folder in the deployed app (KUDU).

Comment: Refer this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77358927/hosting-blazor-wasm-on-azure-webp-images-not-loading/77359601#77359601) and similarly add mimetype for `PDF` as `mimeMap fileExtension=".pdf" mimeType="application/pdf" />`

Comment: Can you please share the screencap of the folder, where does it resides ?

Comment: You were right.  WE couldn't see the pdf folder in the deployed app.  It was in the Publish Ignore file.  Removed it, republished and it now works!  Thank you for  your help @Harshitha

Comment: Glad it worked out.

Comment: Are you using GitHub actions to deploy your web app ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to check when working with `folder/files` is whether the required files/folder is correctly deployed to the `Azure App Service` root directory.

- When we are using GitHub Actions to publish the app, we need to cross check the `.git`=>`info`=>`exclude` file.

[image]

- It contains the details of the folders/files which are excluded.

You have referred Publish Ignore,

- As you are working with `c# asp.net` application,you need to check whether the folder is excluded.
- We can check it in the `.csproj` file or in the `PublishProfiles` => `.pubxml` file.

***`.csproj`:***

```cs
 <ItemGroup>
   <Content Remove="PdfForms\**" />
   <EmbeddedResource Remove="PdfForms\**" />
   <None Remove="PdfForms\**" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

***`.pubxml`:***

[image]