# Use Virtual Applications own web.config instead of roots in Azure Web Application

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App that has a default app in site\wwwroot. Now i want to create a virtual application in it, like this:

1. Virtual Path: / ; Physical Path: site\wwwroot ; Type: Application
2. Virtual Path: /feature ; Physical Path: site\wwwroot\feature ; Type: Application

As you can see, i already created the virtual application with the paths, the folder exists and has its own web.config and everything.

BUT when i go to my website like this: [URL]/feature it loads with all the configurations of the root application. It looks like the virtual application only exists to be able to find the original application with another URL.

How can I have my virtual application use its own web.config and files as a feature branch should? It is part of our release, so it should be automatically created like the principals of the continous deployment say.

I'm expecting to use the virtual applications files as I got the to subURL but instead it uses the root files.

Comment: Are you deploying .Net Core or .Net Framework application?

Comment: It's a .Net Framework application. .Net Framework 4.8

Comment: Below workaround is for .net framework 4.8 itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I have my virtual application use its own web.config and files as a feature branch should?

- To avoid the Virtual Application from picking the root application `Web.config` file, check the [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74948250/19648279) which I have answered on how to deploy Virtual Applications.

[image]

- With the approach I have followed (SO Link), the root directory will not have separate `web.config` file, as we create it from Azure Portal.

[image]

- Only config available will be from the Virtual App folder. Even if you deploy Multiple Virtual Apps, the `web.config` will be accessible only for that particular folder.
- To make sure the configurations are loading from the Virtual App, Check the below Workaround to retrieve App Settings Configuration values in Virtual Application.
- I have given workaround for .NET Framework Application. If you are working with .NET Core, follow the same steps.

***`Web.config` from Virtual App:***

```cs
 <appSettings>
   <add key="ConfigValue" value="Value from Feature App"/>
 </appSettings>
```

***Code to retrieve App Setting***

```cs
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
     DataBind(); 
 }
 string configval = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigValue"];
```

***code in .aspx page:***

```cs
<h3><%# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigValue"] %></h3>
```

***Output:***

***Default App:***
[image]

***Virtual Application:***

[image]

Comment: My applicaiton is a little behind, it's .Net Framework 4.8 based. But the location tag gave me an idea in the web.config. Still not sure how will the application use the whole subdirectory. Do you have any idea how can I apply your suggestions to my version instead of a .Net Core version application?

Comment: Didn't work with my idea about location. Tried to fill up the main config with the other as well seperated by differenet location tags but it wasn't working.

Comment: Example which I gave is for .net framework itself.

Comment: I followed the steps you made, but it is not working correctly. I have 2 web apps in the solutions, service and the actual site. Service shows that i don't have permission to view the page and site has a runtime error in it. I wanted to insert  <customErrors mode="Off"/> in the config to check the real issue but there is no web.config in the folder that was deployed. I mean, there is .debug, .release.config etc but it used the simple web.config before.

Comment: Share your repo if possible.

Comment: sadly it is not possible, it's work related. Let me check the config again, what I'm missing and I'm gonna write again. I'm changing some stuff in the release pipeline that is currently left out so maybe I missed something.

Comment: So I cleaned my projects from the configs, only left 1. web.config that contains everything that is needed to run the app. But after the publish is finished, it is missing from the files that are published.

Comment: Add `<PropertyGroup>
    <PublishIISAssets>true</PublishIISAssets>` as mentioned in the  [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75098214/19648279) to add the missing config file.

Comment: Sadly it didn't change anything. Both of my projects contain this and none of them have the config file in them after the publish.

Comment: Where you are adding the propertyGroup.

Comment: .csproj file has a huge project tag that contains the propertygroup already. PublishIISAssets is the first one in the group now.

Comment: If possbile share your repo once by masking ur client secrets.

Comment: Before that: now after some refreshes, vs reopening and stuff, it throws an error:
3>
3>Could not complete the request to remote agent URL '[my link].
3>Chunked encoding upload is not supported on the HTTP/1.0 protocol.
3>Publish failed to deploy.
3>

Comment: OK i managed to solve the issue, i had more propertygroups it looks like, so i put it in every single one, but the web.config isn't deployed.

Is the publishIISAssets something that can be only applied in a blazor app?

Comment: Yes,I think it is for Blazor .We need to check the equivalent property for WebApp.

Comment: I uploaded manually because of curiousity the web.config and checked what happens. Now the application starts but I can see the following error: 
https://[SITE].azurewebsites.net/App/main.js?v=1.0.0 is not found, which is correct, because it should search for the file under the subdirectory

Comment: Issue is resolved or you are looking for more info ?

Comment: sadly no, it still searches the files in the main directory like how it was when i wrote the question :( And I can't deploy the web.config

Comment: Create web app from portal,that will be your default app.And only publish the sub folder feature app to the create app service and check

Comment: I can't create a new one because of company guidelines, but i cleared it's whole folder before starting to work with your suggestions. The only folder it contains now is the feature folder

Comment: Okay so it turns out it wasn't even an azure-problem. What I didn't realize is that our deprecated (that we all trying to catch up with to be able to work with it) technology has a hyperlink to the main files hidden inside it's root files. So it was basically Durandals fault. I'm going to mark your answer accepted because the azure part was successful. Thank you for your help!